# Many Worlds: What happens to the mass?

Tags: quantum-interpretations, wave-particle-duality

This [question](http://With%20regard%20to%20the%20theory%20that%20each%20time%20a%20wave%20function%20collapses%20the%20universe%20splits%20so%20that%20each%20possible%20outcome%20really%20exists%20-%20where%20does%20all%20the%20energy%20required%20to%20create%20all%20the%20new%20universes%20come%20from?) answers the conservation of energy in many worlds by stating that the overall energy of the system is still conserved by adding up the overall probabilities of and energies of the different states, but glosses over the particle portion of particle wave duality. When an electron splits off into two different states we can use mass and energy interchangeably, but it doesn't account for the fact that you can't get 1/3 of an electron in one universe and 2/3 of an electron in another, particularly for low energy electrons near their rest mass. Where does the missing mass come from?

Comment: Does this help? https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/536522/123208

Comment: Doesn't really address the mass, although I do like the individual who downvoted this question, instead of saying 'we don't know, so go away now.'

Comment: Well, there *is* no missing mass. IMHO, the Deutsch version of MWI makes that pretty clear. Perhaps you got a downvote from someone who really hates MWI.