# Continuous Collapse Interpretation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations, wavefunction-collapse, quantum-measurements

Suppose we interpret quantum mechanics to mean that the collapse randomly happens at every single moment.

1. Wouldn't this be identical to the many worlds interpretation except much less objectional because we're not talking about new universes spawning up?

We lift all of the ideas of Many Worlds Interpretation but simply say that only one of the universes are real.

2. Why would anyone prefer the Copenhagen interpretation over this "continuous collapse interpretation"? Copenhagen interpretation ends up giving a special place to observers, while this interpretation puts all of the material world on an equal footing.

Comment: As I said here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/536580/123208 MWI doesn't require new universes spawning up.

Comment: Your "continuous collapse interpretation" is experimentally disproven since we can maintain the qubits in quantum computers in a superposition for longer than a single moment. That shows collapse cannot happen "every single moment".

Comment: @JohnRennie But I later said that we take all the ideas of many worlds but keep just one world. If that's not continuous collapse, whatever it is, it's not disproven. Many worlds isn't disproven

Comment: This line of ideas has existed for a long time now: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-collapse_theory