# Number of ''Splittings'' in Many Worlds

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations

The many worlds interpretation suggests that the universe (or multiverse, not sure on the terminology) is composed of a superposition of quantum worlds?

It seems like there is a splitting off of worlds whenever a measurement occurs, but don't measurements occur basically infinitely often in quantum mechanics?  So if this splitting off during measurements (I mean measurement in the quantum sense) has been occurring since the Big Bang, does that not mean that the number of worlds is infinite, or even impossible to define?

Can the rate at which measurements have been occurring since the Big Bang be quantified statistically to quantify the number of worlds which now co-exist in ''many worlds''?
'

Comment: My answer to a related question may help: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/536580/123208

Comment: [Sean Carroll explains: what is the many-worlds interpretation?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t_xqNDII--Q)

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.04835

Comment: @Stéphane Rollandin    I'm quoting the concluding sentence in the paper you're referencing:  "It seems to me that much skepticism about Everett’s approach and its many implementations stems from the fact that in
spite of valiant attempts (Deutsch, 1997), the strength of arguments in its
favor does not match the scope of its claim."

Comment: TLDR version of "many worlds:" The wave function is the only reality.