How does the Born rule arise in the many-worlds interpretation with only two worlds?
I’m struggling to understand how probabilities other than strictly 50/50 can arise in the Many-Worlds Interpretation (MWI) of quantum mechanics when the wavefunction appears to split into exactly two worlds during measurement.
For example, consider measuring the spin of an electron in the state $|\psi\rangle = a |\text{up}\rangle + b |\text{down}\rangle$. According to the MWI, instead of the wavefunction collapsing during measurement, decoherence causes it to split into two components (worlds). In one world, the experimenter observes spin up, and in the other, spin down.
Here’s my confusion:

If only two worlds are created, why isn’t the probability of being in each world exactly 50%?
Alternatively, does the Born rule imply that a vast number of worlds are created, with $|a|^2$ of them corresponding to spin up and $|b|^2$ corresponding to spin down? This frequentist-like approach, involving many worlds rather than just two, seems easier to reconcile with the Born rule, but I’m not sure if it’s a valid interpretation within MWI.

Could someone clarify how the Born rule emerges in MWI, especially if only two worlds are involved? Is the idea of “worlds” more nuanced than just a strict count of two?

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/536522/123208

Actually this is a common controversy with MWI. Many critics of MWI criticizes this problem. Much of of the academic work is making MWI work for a state that does not have 50-50% probability between two states.

The MWI is what you get if you take seriously the idea that the equations of motion of quantum theory describe reality.
In classical physics the evolution of a physical quantity, such as the $x$ position of a particle is described by a variable $x(t)$ and if you measure the $x$ position you get the value $x(t)$.
In quantum physics the equations of motion of a physical quantity like the $x$ position are written in terms of a Hermitian operator called an observable $\hat{X}(t)$. The possible results of measuring the $x$ position are given by the eigenvalues of $\hat{X}(t)$ and quantum physics predicts the expectation value $\langle\hat{X}(t)\rangle$ using the relative state $\rho$ which is a Hermitian operator with unit trace according to the Born rule:
$$\langle\hat{X}(t)\rangle=\operatorname{tr}(\rho\hat{X}(t))$$
In quantum theory in general the expectation value of an observable at the end of an experiment depends on what happens to all of the possible values of an observable during the experiment: this is called interference. For an example see Section 2 of this paper
https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9911150
If information is copied out of a system this suppresses interference: an effect called decoherence
https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.06282
For systems you see in everyday life, information is copied out of them on a timescale much shorter than the timescale over which they change significantly so interference is very heavily suppressed. As a result, there are multiple versions of those systems with different values of the monitored observables that evolve autonomously and they form layers each of which evolves approximately like the universe as described by classical physics:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.2189
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0104033
If you measure the $\hat{Z}$ observable of a system $S$ in the state
$$a|\uparrow_z\rangle_S+b|\downarrow_z\rangle_S$$
onto a measuring device $M$ the resulting state looks like this
$$a|\uparrow_z\rangle_S|\uparrow_z\rangle_M+b|\downarrow_z\rangle_S|\downarrow_z\rangle_M$$
One question to ask is how do you expect probabilities to act in reality. You can then look at what quantities actually act as you expect probabilities to act. The probabilities have to respect what information it's possible for you to get out of the system and it has to respect the symmetries of the resulting state. One approach to explaining the Born rule along such lines is called envariance:
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0405161
There are other restrictions you can place on probabilities, like a later measurement can't change the probabilities of results of an earlier measurement. For example, if you measure the state
$$\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}|\uparrow_z\rangle_S+\sqrt{\tfrac{2}{3}}|\downarrow_z\rangle_S$$
the equal probability rule you propose would lead you to say the probability of $\uparrow_z$ is 1/2. But suppose you follow up this measurement by saying that if you get the $\downarrow_z$ you will measure the $\hat{X}$ observable which is unsharp when $\hat{Z}$ is sharp so that now there are three outcomes of the resulting overall measurement. Then the equal probability rule would say the probability of $\uparrow_z$ is 1/3 not 1/2. There is an approach to probability in the MWI where you ask how you could assign probabilities to stop inconsistencies like that from being used to construct a Dutch Book against you and that leads to the Born rule, see
https://arxiv.org/abs/0906.2718
In either case working out probabilities involves using more structure than just the number of worlds.

You write: "Then the equal probability rule would say the probability of ↑z is 1/3 not 1/2"
Why can't it say the probability of ↑z is still 1/2, with the remaining 1/2 split among the rest of the measurements?

@David Quantum theory allows you to treat the overall interaction as one measurement with three outcomes or as two measurements that have been composed together. If you want to treat those situations differently you would have to modify quantum theory.

What exactly is contradicted in quantum theory when we say that, in a measurement with three outcomes, we assign 1/2 to the first outcome and 1/4 + 1/4 to the second and third outcomes? Assume that the wave function initially splits into two components, and then, after an infinitesimally small time, one of the halves splits into two new components.

The motion of the systems in the example I gave goes like this: you do a CNOT from the measured system to the measurement device, then you do a conditional rotation of the spin, then you do a conditional CNOT. Looking at it from the point of view of the matrices involved the overall process is equivalent to measuring an observable with 3 eigenvalues. Your story isn't compatible with that.

You say: "Looking at it from the point of view of the matrices involved the overall process is equivalent to measuring an observable with 3 eigenvalues." I assume that it is being suggested here that the time interval between the measurements is exactly zero—not an infinitesimally small value, but precisely zero. However, in the initial assumption, it was stated that there is an infinitesimal time interval between the two measurements, as reflected in the claim that "a later measurement can't change the probabilities of results of an earlier measurement."

"I assume that it is being suggested here that the time interval between the measurements is exactly zero" No. The amount of time between the measurements doesn't have much to do with anything. The state at the end of the measurements looks exactly like the state you would get if, instead of doing the measurements in the prescribed way, we measured a particular observable with three eigenvalues.

The idea of mapping states in a superposition to worlds isn't consistent. Let's say you're in the state
$$|\psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|\text{up}\rangle_z+|\text{down}\rangle_z\right)$$
in the $z$ basis. If you change your basis to measuring the $x$ direction of spin, the same state reads
$$|\psi \rangle = |\text{up}\rangle_x$$
So is there one world or two? And do those "worlds" contain $x$ eigenstates or $z$ eigenstates or something else? There is a very clear contradiction here.
There has been work in trying to derive a preferred basis (Schlosshauer: Decoherence and the Quantum-to-Classical Transition), but I think in general it does not work. For example, if you try to use a measurement apparatus that measures the sum of spins of two particles, there are still multiple eigenstates of individual spins that are consistent with a given measurement result like total spin $=0$.
My personal understanding is that MWI is more of a way of thinking about things, which sort of works some of the time but gets you into trouble if taken literally. However many (or most?) people who speak of it don't communicate it with the inconsistencies that it comes with. There is another, IMO more damning inconsistency in MWI involving 2 or more measurements on the same system, but the one here is already sufficient to raise serious doubts.
I don't know if you can tell, but I haven't been convinced that MWI is worth taking very seriously.

Doesn't the many-world imply that |up> is entangled with the environment through decoherence, forming a separate "world" , so |up>|env_1> + |down>|env_2> cannot be written in the form |right>|env> that you mentioned in you answer

The "number of worlds" should always just be the dimension of the Hilbert space.

@David In the general case, MWI isn't able to derive a basis post-measurement. It depends what is measured. It's completely possible to have a superposition even after measurement, and for that same state not to be a superposition if $|\psi\rangle$ is put in another basis. If it's just a qubit by itself $\alpha |0\rangle + \beta |1\rangle$, there is no "special basis".
In some cases, you could make a case that a measurement apparatus defines the basis. But the appeal of MWI is that there's nothing special about "measurement" so this then reopens the problem that it was supposed to solve.

@ConnorBehan That is a consistent choice that can be made. But the content of the worlds still doesn't have a consistent definition, in contrast with the common explanation that each term in a superposition corresponds to a world.

@don'ttrainaionme but doesn't a measurement device define what kind of information about a superposed value leaks to the environment, so that it may decohere? Even in many worlds, there's something special about "measurement" I think, there's just not something UNIQUE about measurement. Measurement isn't this magically different thing that happens, measurement is just two particles exchanging entanglement... or something...
